# Decrypting HTTPS packets using pcap4J

Tags: java, ssl, https, fiddler, pcap4j

In `Java` I'm using [`pcap4J`](https://github.com/kaitoy/pcap4j) to capture network traffic of another application running on my computer. The code I'm using to do this is the following:

```
import org.pcap4j.core.*;
import org.pcap4j.packet.Packet;
import org.pcap4j.util.NifSelector;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.pcap4j.core.BpfProgram.BpfCompileMode.OPTIMIZE;
import static org.pcap4j.core.PcapNetworkInterface.PromiscuousMode.PROMISCUOUS;

public class Pcap4jLoop
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception
    {
        PcapNetworkInterface networkDevice = getNetworkDevice();

        try (PcapHandle handle = networkDevice.openLive(65536, PROMISCUOUS, 50))
        {
            String serverIP = "..."; // Filter for packets with just one server
            String bpfExpression = "dst host " + serverIP + " || src host " + serverIP;
            handle.setFilter(bpfExpression, OPTIMIZE);

            PacketListener listener = packet -> printPacket(packet, handle);

            handle.loop(Integer.MAX_VALUE, listener);

            //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement,StatementWithEmptyBody
            while (true)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private static PcapNetworkInterface getNetworkDevice() throws IOException
    {
        NifSelector nifSelector = new NifSelector();
        PcapNetworkInterface nif = nifSelector.selectNetworkInterface();
        if (nif == null)
        {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return nif;
    }

    private static void printPacket(Packet packet, PcapHandle pcapHandle)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("A packet captured at ")
                .append(pcapHandle.getTimestampPrecision())
                .append(":");
        System.out.println(sb);
        System.out.println(packet);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the traffic is encrypted and therefore useless to analyze. Another application called [`Fiddler`](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is however able to decrypt the traffic just fine without any special configuration or private key of the server. Fiddler can display the `JSON` structures being exchanged which I'm interested in. How can I do the same thing in `Java` code in order to work with the captured `JSON` objects? (This question is about the decryption part, not the parsing afterwards)

Comment: Fiddler does it by being a man-in-the-middle, not by decrypting traffic sent directly between two other computers.

Comment: Also, while Fiddler does not need special configuration the client needs a special configuration, i.e. it needs to trust the certificate authority used by fiddler to dynamically create certificates.

Comment: By definition you can not decrypt any TLS traffic (so that includes HTTPS) if you do not control either side or are able to have either side give you the negotiated master key and client random used. There are ample tutorials on how to do that. But just trying to decrypt any random TLS traffic will not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As by the commenters on this question:

> By definition you can not decrypt any `TLS` traffic (so that includes
>   `HTTPS`) if you do not control either side or are able to have either
>   side give you the negotiated master key and client random used. Just trying to decrypt 
>   any random `TLS` traffic will not be possible. `Fiddler` does it by being
>   a man-in-the-middle, not by decrypting traffic sent directly between
>   two other computers. While `Fiddler` does not need special configuration the client 
>   needs a special configuration, i.e. it needs to trust the certificate
>   authority used by `Fiddler` to dynamically create certificates.